# MySQL Displaying columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables: book & publisher

book columns are: book_code, title, publisher_code

publisher columns are: publisher_code, publisher_name

I am trying to display each book title with it's book_code, publisher_code, & publisher_name

so far this is what I have:

```
select book_code, title, a.publisher_code
from book a
inner join publisher p
on a.publisher_code = p.publisher_code;
```

I'm unsure how to also display the publisher_name

Comment: `SELECT A.book_Code, A.Title, A.Publisher_code, P.Publisher_name` you simply need to add it to the select, you should also reference the the table name alias containing the publisher's name.  Simply add each column to the select statement that you want to see in the results! when two or more tables have a column named the same, you must define what table you want the data from as you've done with publisher_Code.  I would get in the habit of always aliasing the tables when more than one is involved, it avoids ambiguity later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql here is how I would have wrote it:

```
SELECT
  b.book_code,
  b.title,
  b.publisher_code,
  p.publisher_name
FROM
  book AS b
    JOIN publisher AS p USING (publisher_code);
```

Comment: Thanks,  I wasn't aware that you could select from multiple tables in the beginning select statement.

Comment: You could try also `SELECT * FROM ...` or `SELECT b.*, p.* FROM ...` in phpmyadmin and see all the coloms (it's not advised when you only need one element, but when you do actually need all of them.

Comment: `publisher_code` could be an issue because it exists in several tables, then `SELECT *, b.publisher_code AS publisher_code ...` can be your friend